# Split array into groups of three instead of groups of two

Tags: arrays, bash

Currently I have this backup script working just fine in Unraid.
I can add as many backup jobs to the array below as I like and the script will loop through these one after the other until all are done.

```
#!/bin/bash

# backup source to destination
backup_jobs=(
# source                         # destination
"/mnt/user/isos"                 "/mnt/disks/Backup"
"/mnt/user/data"               "/mnt/disks/Backup"
)

# loop through all backup jobs
for i in "${!backup_jobs[@]}"; do

    # get source path and skip to next element
    ! (( i % 2 )) && src_path="${backup_jobs[i]}" && continue

    # get destination path
    dst_path="${backup_jobs[i]}"
    
    #run backup
    rsync -av --delete --log-file=/mnt/disks/Backup/rsync-logs/log.`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`.log --progress --exclude '.Recycle.Bin' "$src_path" "$dst_path"
```

Now I would like to also have a subfolder for the rsync-logs per backup job.

For that I'd like to add a name to the array for each job - but I cannot figure out how to get the loop to load that **3rd variable** per line per loop like the other 2 variables.
:(

```
backup_jobs=(
    # source                    # destination         # jobname
    "/mnt/user/isos"            "/mnt/disks/Backup"   "isos"
    "/mnt/user/data"            "/mnt/disks/Backup"   "backup"
    )
```

Anyone able to help? :)

Comment: It would probably be easier if you used 3 separate arrays instead of trying to merge it all into a single array.

Comment: What you really need is 2-dimensional arrays, but bash doesn't have them.

Comment: (Speaking to the original title:) Semantically speaking, there's nothing "per line" about it. Two array elements on the same line of source parse into the exact same array as if you wrote it one item per line alternating source and destination on separate lines. The logic doesn't know or care how many items are written on each line; it only needs to know what to divide the offsets by, and what to do with each possible remainder of that division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `i % 3` instead of `i % 2`. This will be `0` for the source path, `1` for the destination path, and `2` for the job name.

```
for i in "${!backup_jobs[@]}"; do
    case $(($i % 3)) in
        0) src_path="${backup_jobs[i]}"; continue ;;
        1) dst_path="${backup_jobs[i]}"; continue ;;
        2) job_name="${backup_jobs[i]}" ;;
    esac
    
    #run backup
    rsync -av --delete --log-file=/mnt/disks/Backup/rsync-logs/"$job_name"/log.`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`.log --progress --exclude '.Recycle.Bin' "$src_path" "$dst_path"
done
```

Comment: This is good but quite a waste of resources to re-implement an arguments stack using shell arithmetic on an array index; rather than using a function with built-in support for an arguments stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A backup_jobs=(
        [source,1]="/mnt/user/isos" 
        [destination,1]="/mnt/disks/Backup"
        [jobname,1]="isos"
        [foo,1]="foo" 
        [bar,1]="bar"
        [source,2]="/mnt/user/data" 
        [destination,2]="/mnt/disks/Backup" 
        [jobname,2]="backup"
        [foo,2]="foo" 
        [bar,2]="bar"
)

LEN=$(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"${!backup_jobs[@]}"|sort -r|sed -n 's/.*,//; 1p')

for((i=1; i<=LEN; i++)); do
   echo "------- Backup $i -------"
   echo "source: ${backup_jobs[source,$i]}"
   echo "destination: ${backup_jobs[destination,$i]}"
   echo "jobname: ${backup_jobs[jobname,$i]}"
   
   #  rsync -av --delete --log-file=/mnt/disks/Backup/rsync-logs/${backup_jobs[jobname,$i]}/log.`date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S'`.log --progress --exclude '.Recycle.Bin' "${backup_jobs[source,$i]}" "${backup_jobs[destination,$i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
------- Backup 1 -------
source: /mnt/user/isos
destination: /mnt/disks/Backup
jobname: isos
------- Backup 2 -------
source: /mnt/user/data
destination: /mnt/disks/Backup
jobname: backup
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a function which benefit of built-in arguments stack features is certainly a more appropriate and direct approach; rather than re-implementing the arguments stack using shell arithmetic on array indexes.

With bash array:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

backup_jobs=(
  # source                    # destination         # jobname
  "/mnt/user/isos"            "/mnt/disks/Backup" "isos"
  "/mnt/user/data"            "/mnt/disks/Backup" "backup"
)

do_backup() {
  while
    src_path=$1
    dst_path=$2
    job_name=$3
    shift 3 2> /dev/null
  do #run backup
    echo rsync \
      --archive --verbose --delete \
      --log-file="/mnt/disks/Backup/rsync-logs/$job_name/log.$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S').log" \
      --progress --exclude '.Recycle.Bin' \
      "$src_path" "$dst_path"
  done
}

do_backup "${backup_jobs[@]}"
```

Now even an array is not necessary, and it can stick to the POSIX-shell grammar:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

do_backup() {
  while
    src_path=$1
    dst_path=$2
    job_name=$3
    shift 3 2> /dev/null
  do #run backup
    echo rsync \
      --archive --verbose --delete \
      --log-file="/mnt/disks/Backup/rsync-logs/$job_name/log.$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S').log" \
      --progress --exclude '.Recycle.Bin' \
      "$src_path" "$dst_path"
  done
}

  # source                    # destination         # jobname
do_backup \
  "/mnt/user/isos"            "/mnt/disks/Backup"  "isos" \
  "/mnt/user/data"            "/mnt/disks/Backup"  "backup"
```

Comment: I've never seen that syntax of variable assignments after `while`. How does that work?

Comment: @Barmar the shell `while ... do ... done` accepts two commands blocks. The return code of the first commands block is used as the condition to enter the second commands block. There is nothing special about the assignments here. Those assign the arguments value to variables and does not count for the condition. Only the return code of the `shift 3 2> /dev/null` is used as condition to execute the loop.

Comment: I just didn't realize it would allow the condition block to be on a new line without backslash.